# How to get the latest value of a time duration (let's say for 1 minute) in Kusto table

Tags: postgresql, max, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to find the latest value of a column for particular time duration(1 minute in my case) from Kusto table.
I have timeseries data in PostgreSQL table and I am using `last()` function (https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/last/)to find the latest value of `scaled_value` for `1 minute time bucket` of PostgreSQL and I want to use same function in Kusto Table to  get the latest value of `scaled_value` . What will be correct function to use in Kusto corresponding to `last()` function in Postgresql

**Code I am using in PostgreSQL :**

```
SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_bucket('1 minutes', timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') * 1000 AS BIGINT) as timestamp_epoch,
vessel_telemetry.timeSeries, 
last(vessel_telemetry.scaled_value, vessel_telemetry.timestamp) as scaled_value, 
FROM shipping.vessel_telemetry 
WHERE vessel_telemetry.ingested_timestamp >= '2022-07-20T10:10:58.71Z' AND vessel_telemetry.ingested_timestamp < '2022-07-20T10:15:33.703985Z' 
GROUP BY time_bucket('1 minutes', vessel_telemetry.timestamp), vessel_telemetry.vessel_timeSeries
```

**Corresponding code I am using in ADX**

```
VesselTelemetry_DS 
| where ingested_timestamp >= datetime(2022-07-20T10:10:58.71Z) and ingested_timestamp < datetime(2022-07-20T10:15:33.703985Z) 
| summarize max_scaled_value = max(scaled_value) by bin(timestamp, 1m), timeSeries 
| project timestamp_epoch =(datetime_diff('second', timestamp, datetime(1970-01-01)))*1000, timeSeries, max_scaled_value
```

The data that i am getting using PostgreSQL is not matching with the data I am getting from ADX Query. I think the functionality of `last()`  function of Postgre is different from `max()` function of ADX. Is there any function in ADX that we can use to perform same as `last()` of PSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

`arg_max (ExprToMaximize, * | ExprToReturn [, ...])`

Please note the order of the parameters, which is opposite to [Timescale's last()](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/last/) -
First the expression to maximize, in your case `timestamp` and then the expression(s) to return, in your case `scaled_value`

Comment: Yes I tried this but it is giving  max value for 1 min and not the latest value .What I want is to get the last value for 1 minute. For ex in 1 min we have this data [1,3,5,2] and I want last data i.e. 2 and using arg_max I will get 5. I think last() function in Postgresql don't return max value for a time duration, it return the latest value based on time within that aggregated group

Comment: As I said - Note the order of the parameters. For arg_max you should first give the expression to maximize, in your case `timestamp` and only than the expression(s) to return, in your case `scaled_value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It worked as required and Yes I was giving wrong order of parameters. By giving correct order it is now working fine